# How to request intra day real time option data using ibPY?

Tags: options, programming, python, interactive-brokers

For example, price, iv, delta, gamma, volume, and open interest

Answer (score 1):

Interactive Brokers posted a webinar on Dec 13 2016 about using IBridgePy to connect to IB's API. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hogXB07OJ_I.
It is pretty easy to request real time price of option data. You may check out the website of IBridgePy at www.IBridgePy.com
To learn how to use it, you may refer to its documentation.